# Why does [[NSNumber alloc] init] return nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know I should use the designated initializer to `init` a `NSNumber`. But when I find that:
`[[NSNumber alloc] init]` returns nil, I am still a little surprised.
What has been done in implementation of `NSNumber` to return `nil` for `init` (after all, `NSObject` will return `self`)? Does it try to `init` the underlying `__NSCFNumber` at first in the designated initializers? So if you go through the default `init`, it returns `nil` as the underlaying `__NSCFNumber` is `nil`. Why doesn't it just declare the `init` and `new` as `NS_UNAVAILABLE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the overridden `init` for `NSNumber` simply returns `nil`.  This is valid [if an object cannot be created for some reason](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1418641-init).

It isn't valid to call this initialiser as an object cannot be created without knowing what sort of number you want.

The reason that it isn't marked as `NS_UNAVAILABLE` is that that macro was only introduced in 2014.

[NSNumber](http://www.nextcomputers.org/NeXTfiles/Docs/NeXTStep/3.3/nd/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber.htmld/index.html) is much older than that. 20 years older.  It dates back to [NeXTSTEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NeXTSTEP) from 1994 (That is what the `NS` prefix means on all of those classes).  Adding that macro would be a breaking change.